# Async Tasks fetching json from api's not runnin async

Tags: c#, json, asynchronous

I'm new to async Task in c#. What I want to accomplish is following:
- Api that calls 3 other api's async 
- Return 3 datatsets as one

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
public async Task<string> ServiceModelsForTournamentBase(int id)
    {
        var matchInfoJson = await GetJsonFromApi("api/asyncdata/searchmatchfortournament/" + id, _siteUrl);
        var scoringPlayersJson = await GetJsonFromApi("api/asyncdata/scoringplayersfortournament/" + id, _siteUrl);
        var teamsJson = await GetJsonFromApi("api/asyncdata/tournamentteams/" + id, _siteUrl);

    // return json containing all three
    }

private async Task<string> GetJsonFromApi(string serviceUrl, Uri siteUrl)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = siteUrl;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var response = await client.GetAsync(serviceUrl);
            return response.IsSuccessStatusCode
                ? await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                : string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does you mean its not fetching it asynchronously? Because I guarantee you that it is. Do you mean concurrently?

Comment: You're correct, I actually meant concurrently. Bad wording there. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
public async Task<string> ServiceModelsForTournamentBase(int id)
    {
        var jsons = await Task.WhenAll(
              GetJsonFromApi("api/asyncdata/searchmatchfortournament/" + id, _siteUrl),
              GetJsonFromApi("api/asyncdata/scoringplayersfortournament/" + id, _siteUrl),
              GetJsonFromApi("api/asyncdata/tournamentteams/" + id, _siteUrl)
        );
        var matchInfoJson = jsons[0];
        var scoringPlayersJson = jsons[1];
        var teamsJson = jsons[2];

    // return json containing all three
    }
```